# why I make transaction already active in jsf and jpa project?

Tags: java, primefaces

```
ERROR allList Transaction already active
Hata SelectedProjectDetail: Transaction already active
ERROR allList Transaction already active
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, somewhere you are invoking `tr.begin()` on already started transaction...  You can surround your `tr.begin()` with an `if` block to check that your transaction is not already active..

```
if (!tr.active()) {
    tr.begin();
}
```

**Where**: - `tr` is your `Transaction` reference..

Comment: `JPA` transactions doesn't work that way :) [Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions). The question is far too abstract.

Comment: @AmitD.. Thanks.. I have just told him where OP might be wrong.. So, he can find out what way this works in JPA.. I haven't use JPA for long, so I don't really remember how I used it there.. But thanks for the link..  :)